# How to use a USE inside a BEGIN ... END block?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Trying to have a single SQL script that works on a number of environments, but the `USE` statement causes an error for the *other* environment, i.e. in the example below, when running against SQL02, the `USE [application]`, even when inside a `BEGIN ... END`?

```
-- connected to SQL02
DECLARE @STAGE INTEGER = 3
IF @@SERVERNAME = 'SQL02' 
    SET @STAGE = 1
IF @@SERVERNAME = 'SQL03' 
    SET @STAGE = 2

IF @STAGE = 1 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    [application_tst].[sys].[database_principals]
                    WHERE   name = N'qauser' ) 
            BEGIN
                USE [application_tst]
                --rest of code
            END
    END

IF @STAGE = 2 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    [application].[sys].[database_principals]
                    WHERE   name = N'qauser' ) 
            BEGIN
                USE [application]
                --rest of code
            END
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use explicit three part names everywhere and not use `USE`. USE is an execution time command and your batch will fail to *compile* as expected because you expect the name resolution to occur as if the USE was *executed* during *compilation*.

```
-- connected to SQL02
DECLARE @STAGE INTEGER = 3
IF @@SERVERNAME = 'SQL02' 
    SET @STAGE = 1
IF @@SERVERNAME = 'SQL03' 
    SET @STAGE = 2

IF @STAGE = 1 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    [application_tst].[sys].[database_principals]
                    WHERE   name = N'qauser' ) 
            BEGIN
                select from [application_tst].dbo.table
                insert into [application_tst].dbo.table
                --rest of code, using explicit 3 part names
            END
    END

IF @STAGE = 2 
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                    FROM    [application].[sys].[database_principals]
                    WHERE   name = N'qauser' ) 
            BEGIN
                select from [application].dbo.table
                insert into [application].dbo.table
                --rest of code, using explicit 3 part names
            END
    END
```

An alternative is to use [dynamic sql](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), which will delay compilation until is invoked.

Comment: Ah, just tried this with **DROP USER [basic]** and the  three part name syntax is invalid  :-(

Comment: for that one (and any other similar name) either use dynamic sql or create a stored proc usp_dropuser *in each db* and call the SP by 3 part name explicitly. The later option is unnecessarily complex imho, I would say dynamic sql is fine in this case.

Comment: And the solution I used was ... EXEC(
'USE application; 
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
FROM    sys.database_principals
WHERE   name = N''qauser'' ) 
DROP USER [qauser] 
')